# How to disable Checkstyle and PMD checking in Eclipse Oxygen?

Tags: eclipse, maven, checkstyle, m2e, pmd

I'm using Eclipse with the Checkstyle and PMD plugins, and the m2e integration of those. When the project builds, it both slows down the build a bit, but crucially hangs at about 58% while "checking file Foo.java", with a bunch of PMD checks queued. I tried selecting all open projects and choosing "Deactivate Checkstyle" as per an older answer on SO, but this still happens. (And the build progress messages mention invoking "Checkstyle builder.")

Is there a way to disable this automatic CheckStyle and PMD behaviour without uninstalling the plug-ins? Possibly by doing surgery on the .project files or the Maven settings? I'd still like to have those available within Eclipse manually, because our workflow mandates only zero-warning code passes code review, and I'm too new at the company to just suppress the ones that are inconvenient like the seniors.

Comment: pmd-eclipse-plugin slows down project import for us so much oxygen is unusable :-(

Answer (score 2):

You can put the checkstyle and pmd configuration (in the pom) into a profile. Then you can activate/deactivate the profile by various means, including command line, marker files and operating system.

Comment: Will Eclipse's integration honour this though? I can skip the checks already in a command-line build. (Also I'm not keen on touching the POMs of this 100-module beast.)

Comment: You can right click on your project and use "Maven -> Select Maven Profiles" and choose the profiles you want to activate.